# How to send static html file for dynamic routes in nest.js

Tags: express, nest

I'm moving my existing project written on Express.js to Nest.js and one of the most pressing problem is to serve static html page for changing user's password. I've been looking for any answer for a couple of days, unsuccessfully. My implementation on Express.js works perfectly, here it is:

```
resetPass.use(express.static(__dirname + "/reset_pass_page"));

resetPass.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
  // here I check ID which is JWT and if everything is OK I send the form:
      res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + "/reset_pass_page/index.html");
  }
```

And now I'm trying to reach the same outcome using Nest.js. I got one single module for resetting password and sending links to user's email. Here is the controller:

```
@Controller('users/resetpass')
export class ResetPassController {
  constructor(private readonly resetPassService: ResetPassService) { }

  // here is others routes for getting reset link on user's email and etc...

  // in this part I'm sending the form:
  @Get("requestform/:id")
  sendResetPasswordForm(@Param("id") resetToken: string) {
    return this.resetPassService.sendResetPasswordForm(resetToken)
  }
}
```

And what should I do in the service in my case?

```
async sendResetPasswordForm(resetToken: string) {
  try {
  // checking resetToken and if it's OK send form like:
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/reset_pass_page/index.html");
  What method should i use in that case?
  }
}
```

I've already tried to use ServeStaticModule in my reset pass modle, but I can't make it work properly with dynamic routes. I've tried this config:

```
 ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
   rootPath: join(__dirname, '../../../static/resetpass'),
   renderPath: /(\/users\/resetpass\/requestform\/)([\w-]*\.[\w-]*\.[\w-]*)/g,
}),
```

I can make it work for routes without ID, like *users/resetpass/*, but I need to these page be available only for routes like *users/resetpass/:id*.

I'm looking forward for any help and advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to what you did in Express.js:

```
res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + "/reset_pass_page/index.html");
```

You can also use `.sendFile` in Nest.js

```ts
@Get("requestform/:id")
sendResetPasswordForm(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
  const resetTokenPath = this.resetPassService.sendResetPasswordForm(pararms.id)
  res.sendFile(join(__dirname, resetTokenPath, '/reset_pass_page/index.html'));
}
```

You have to add a couple of decorators and types from Express:

```
import { Controller, Get, Res, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response, Request } from 'express';
```